# LightSwitch 2011: Validate Child

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a screen in LightSwitch the has a parent entity and a child entity.  I wrote code in the parent entity validate method that verifies the child records meet specific business rules.  The validation rules run properly when a user creates or edits the parent, but the code is not triggered at all if only the child is edited.  What do I need to do validate the child at server save time everytime either the parent or child records are modified.

Below is a sample validation rule that verifies the sum of the child entity rows equals 100%:

```
partial void MarketingCampaign_Metrics_Validate(MarketingCampaign_Metric entity, EntitySetValidationResultsBuilder results)
{
   if (entity.MarketingCampaign_AllocationRegions.Sum(r => r.RevenuePercent) != Convert.ToDecimal(100))
   {
      results.AddEntityError("The Regions section Revenue (%) does not equal 100%.");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a really simple solution that didn't require moving my current validation code.  I added the following rows to the child object validations:

```
    entity.MarketingCampaign_Metric.RowUpdateDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    entity.MarketingCampaign_Metric.UpdatedBy = this.Application.User.FullName;
```

By updating the parent during the child validation phase, the parent was flagged as changed which forced the parent entity's validation code.

This solution also solved another problem that I had which is I wanted the UpdatedBy field and RowUpdateDate to change if the child entity was modified.  I already am tracking all entity changes in a table and provide auditing screens for end users to review the data changes, but this makes it slightly easier to see who last touched a record even if it was only a child record.  From the perspective of the data administrators of this LightSwitch application, a change to the child is a change to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the same check in two different entities, extract the logic into a method that can be called from both the parent entity & the child entity.

Sounds simple to me, or am I missing something?

And, I'd be calling the method from the *ParentOrChildEntity_Saving* method (where *ParentOrChildEntity* is either the name of the parent entity, or the child entity) rather than in any *Validate* method.

Comment: I tried adjusting the code to do this, but I couldn't figure out how to get this to generate a validation error.  It appears I can only generate validation errors that show up in the UI during the Validate methods.  Maybe I could have returned a general exception which might have been handled, but I didn't try this since I was specifically trying to make these events show up in the validation screen list.